# Decrement-ing Number when a javascript parameter is passed

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

See I'm having this problem when i pass an argument from my database to a javascript function i get a number that decrements and also it's a different number from what i expect to show up

the format of what im passing is (####-####)

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
 session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] != "")
{

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="TopContainer">
    <div id="user">
        <div id="msg">
            <a href="logout.php">
                <button type="button" style="width:60px;float:right;padding:5px;" class="submit">
                    Log Out
                </button>
            </a>

            <span style="float:left;">
                Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="main.php" method="POST" id="form" name="form">
    <div id="box" name="box" style="-webkit-transition:1s;overflow:hidden;">
        <label class="boxes"><input type="checkbox" id="All" name="All" onclick="checkAll()" /><span>All</span></label>
        <label class="boxes"><input type="checkbox" id="books" name="books" onclick="rmOthers(1)"/><span>Books</span></label>
        <label class="boxes"><input type="checkbox" id="journals" name="journals" onclick="rmOthers(2)"/><span>Journals</span></label>
        <label class="boxes"><input type="checkbox" id="guidelines" name="guidelines" onclick="rmOthers(3)"/><span>Guidelines</span></label>
        <label class="boxes"><input type="checkbox" id="pe" name="pe" onclick="rmOthers(4)"/><span>Patient Education</span></label>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="submit" id="hide" style="padding:15px 20px;"  onclick="hideBoxes()">+</button><input type="search" name="search" class="inputs" placeholder="Search Articles" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : ""; ?>" /><button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" >Search</button><br />
        <div id="sq">
            <select id="sqType" style="width:5%;">
            <option class="ar">And</option>
            <option class="ar">Or</option>
            </select>
            <input type="search" class="inputs" placeholder="Filter Results" name="filter" style="width:70%;" value='<?php echo (isset($_POST['filter']) ? $_POST['filter'] : ''); ?>' />
            <button type='submit' id="fil" name='btn_filter' class="submit" style="-webkit-transform:translateX(-5px) translateY(-3px); width:7%;" >Filter</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="BottomContainer">
<?php

if((isset($_POST['submit'])) || (isset($_POST['btn_filter'])))
{
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['search']);

$sql = (strcmp($search, "") == true ? "SELECT * FROM tbl_additionals JOIN tbl_general_info WHERE tbl_general_info.reference_number LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_general_info.title LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_general_info.author LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_additionals.abstract LIKE '%$search%'" : "SELECT * FROM tbl_additionals JOIN tbl_general_info WHERE tbl_general_info.reference_number LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_general_info.title LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_general_info.author LIKE '%$search%' OR tbl_additionals.abstract LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 30");

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0)
{

    while($run = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {   
        $reference = (string)$run['reference_number'];
        $title = (strlen($run['title']) > 121) ? substr($run['title'], 0, strpos(wordwrap($run['title'], 121), "\n")) . '...' : $run['title'];

echo '<div class="SearchResults">';
echo "      <span class='top'>";
echo "          <a>";
echo "              <h3>". strtoupper($title) ."</h3>";
echo "          </a>";
echo "          <br />";
echo "          <h5 class='sub'>";
echo  $run['reference_number'];
echo "          Authors :<a class='authors'>Dr.Michael Ramsay</a><a class='authors'>Dr.Lars Benitez</a><a class='authors'>Dr.Kevin John Pascual</a><br><br>";
echo "          </h5>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <span class='bottom'>";
echo "          <span class='bottomLeft'>";
echo                    ($run['abstract'] != "" ? "             <a class='options' onclick='showOverlay(".$reference.")'>Abstract</a><span style='margin:0px 5px;'>|</span>" : "" );
echo "              <a target='_blank' href='view.php?filename=NKTI  Proceedings  vol. 1 no. 1 Feb.  1996' class='options'>";
echo "                  Full Article";
echo "              </a>";  
echo "          </span>";
echo "          <div class='overlay' id='". $run['reference_number'] ."' onclick='hideOverlay(this, event)'> ";
echo "              <iframe class='abstract' src='abstract.php?id=".$run['reference_number']."' style='padding:0px;' scrolling='no'>";  
echo "              </iframe>";
echo "          </div>";
echo "          <span class='bottomRight'>";
echo "              <p class='label'>NKTI Proceedings volume 1, January - April 2015 @ Pg. 1-15</p>";
echo "          </span>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <br style='clear:both;'/>";
echo "</div>";


    }

}

}

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    echo "<script>alert('Please Login To Continue');window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";
}
?>
```

here's my javascript code

```
function showOverlay(id)
    {
        alert(id);
        document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = "block";
        document.getElementById(id).style['opacity'] = "1";
    }
```

i just made that alert statement just so i can see what the program is passing on javascript here's what happens

[image: ...]

i clicked on the first abstract link that showed up as you can see i echoed out that should be passed before the authors then what is passed is on the alert box

i cant seem to find what's wrong here is it my mysql statement or the javascript code or the php code

Comment: as a side-note you can use console.log(variable here) to see what the values are

Comment: what's console.log? and how will it help me debug my program ?

Comment: You are not showing the code that writes the PHP value to the client side.

Comment: It logs the results in the Javascript console which is usually accessible by pressing F12 in your browser - Read up on console.log() otherwise you'll never get too far in Javascript

Comment: @James Wilkins : I don't get you, what do you mean code that writes the PHP value to the client side ?

Comment: @YesSir Can you post a bit of the processed HTML from the search(?) result page? This will help identify where the error is occurring. It seems that JS or PHP is subtracting 0001 from 1999 somewhere along the way which is what would result in your new four digit `id` number.

Comment: How does the value for 'id' in `showOverlay(id)` get passed in?

Comment: @ codyogden : i think you're right the digits are subtracting cause the argument that was passed wasn't in string format

can you please tell me how i can make it a string im being confused on so many quotes

on this part `($run['abstract'] != "" ? "             <a class='options' onclick='showOverlay(".$run['reference_number'].")'>Abstract</a><span style='margin:0px 5px;'>|</span>" : "" );
`

Comment: I figured it out. Hold on. Answering.

Comment: sure, i updated my question and pasted my whole source code for the search

Comment: The problem is in Javascript. That is the file we need.

Comment: i posted the javascript function on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the ID to the Abstract link and change `showOverlay(".$reference.")` to `onclick='showOverlay(this.dataset.articlenum)'` See the line in PHP below:

### PHP

```
echo ($run['abstract'] != "" ? "<a class='options' data-articlenum='" . $reference . "' onclick='showOverlay(this.dataset.articlenum)'>Abstract</a><span style='margin:0px 5px;'>|</span>" : "" );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/0eea7gxw/

Comment: you got it yes, but from here comes up another problem.


i can't put an id on my anchor tag, i reference that id to show my div overlay which has an id to be passed on showOverlay() function

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use a `data` attribute and reference it in the JS.